# Excel formula that reads a color in one cell and puts a value in another based on that color

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to set up an if statement formula that will read the color of one cell and place a value in another based on that color. I have tried writing several if statements to do this but cant find one to read the color. The sheet is set up to read a date cell. I have conditional formatting set up to color my weekends. I need a value "200" to show on days that are not on weekends and "0" to show on weekends.

Comment: From my experience there is no an easy approach. I would suggest 2 options. 1 - add additional columns put there same formulas as in conditional formatting, then you'll be able to do IF based on that additional column. 2 - you could do the same without additional columns, but your IF would be more difficult, you would need to incorporate your conditional formatting formula to give value and then use IF statements based on that value.

Answer (score 2):

If you were able to do the conditional formatting, you should be able to use a similar formula to input the value. I am guessing it reads the date cell, figures if it is the weekend or not and then inputs the value.

Comment: That is true and works the problem I am running into is on Holidays. I want to be able to just change the color of the date cell and it update the rest of the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, for example, the non-weekends are Red (vbRed) then create a UDF (VBA, Add Module and paste the following:

```
Public Function checkColor(cell)
If cell.Interior.Color = vbRed Then
    checkColor = 200
Else
    checkColor = 0
End If
End Function
```

To use the function:

For example to check A1 and put 0 or 200 in B1, in B1 type

```
=checkColor(A1)
```

Comment: This method won't work with conditional formatting which is OP's requirement.